# Android XmlPullParser with java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, android, eclipse, exception, android-emulator

I'm new to Android development. And now I am learning to use XmlPullParser to read XML file by watch a video tutorial. However after completing my code, I met this Exception problem, and I am pretty sure that I used the same code as the code in the video. Can anyone help me to point out what is the problem?

My MainActivity Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    List<City> cityList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void click(View v) {

        InputStream is = getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("weather.xml");

        XmlPullParser xp = Xml.newPullParser();

        try {
            xp.setInput(is, "utf-8");

            int type = xp.getEventType();
            City city = null;

            while (type != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {

                switch (type) {
                case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:

                    if ("weather".equals(xp.getName())) {
                        cityList = new ArrayList<City>();
                    }
                    else if ("city".equals(xp.getName())) {

                        city = new City();
                    }
                    else if ("name".equals(xp.getName())) {

                        String name = xp.nextText();
                        city.setName(name);
                    }
                    else if ("temp".equals(xp.getName())) {
                        String temp = xp.nextText();
                        city.setTemp(temp);
                    }
                    else if ("pm".equals(xp.getName())) {
                        String pm = xp.nextText();
                        city.setPm(pm);
                    }                   
                    break;

                case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                    if ("city".equals(xp.getName())) {

                        cityList.add(city);
                    }
                    break;
                }               

                type = xp.next();
            }

            for (City c : cityList) {
                System.out.println("haha");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
    }
}
```

And the Logcat error shows:

> 09-06 19:23:07.411: W/System.err(1066): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
>   09-06 19:23:07.411: W/System.err(1066):    at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.setInput(KXmlParser.java:1615)
>   09-06 19:23:07.420: W/System.err(1066):    at com.example.pullparser.MainActivity.click(MainActivity.java:33)
>   09-06 19:23:07.420: W/System.err(1066):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   09-06 19:23:07.431: W/System.err(1066):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   09-06 19:23:07.431: W/System.err(1066):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3039)
>   09-06 19:23:07.440: W/System.err(1066):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
>   09-06 19:23:07.450: W/System.err(1066):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
>   09-06 19:23:07.450: W/System.err(1066):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
>   09-06 19:23:07.450: W/System.err(1066):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>   09-06 19:23:07.460: W/System.err(1066):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   09-06 19:23:07.470: W/System.err(1066):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
>   09-06 19:23:07.470: W/System.err(1066):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   09-06 19:23:07.470: W/System.err(1066):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   09-06 19:23:07.480: W/System.err(1066):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
>   09-06 19:23:07.480: W/System.err(1066):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
>   09-06 19:23:07.490: W/System.err(1066):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   09-06 19:24:07.570: D/dalvikvm(191): GC_CONCURRENT freed 385K, 9% free 6973K/7623K, paused 6ms+7ms
>   : E/(): Device disconnected

Thank you for your kind help!

Comment: Which line is line 33?

Comment: xp.setInput(is, "utf-8");  @immibis